# Cannot read property 'xxx.xxx' of undefined

Tags: react-native, meteor, ecmascript-6

Upgrading `meteor` (from 1.4 to 1.7) and `react` (from 15.3.2 to 16.8.6).  Using Meteor Atmosphere.

At one part of the code whereby to process a delete instruction, the console having the following familiar but clueless error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayConfirmation' of undefined
    at remove (ticket.js:48)
    at onClick (list.jsx:180)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54371)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54420)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54475)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54489)
    at executeDispatch (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54572)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:54597)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:57461)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (modules.js?hash=199fa8ade393a4d3c92b5b590836441c4936d1d6:57470)
```

**Expectation:** Pop up of a dialog box asking for confirmation before delete.

Below are part of the codes:

**components/list.jsx**

```
...
onClick={() => actions.delete && remove()}><img src={require('/crm/images/icon_delete.png')}/> Delete all selected</span>
...
```

**actions/ticket.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { push, goBack } from 'react-router-redux';
import { reset, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';

import { notify, confirm } from '../../core/actions';

import {Tickets} from '../../../../lib/collections';

import {
  SELECT_TICKETS, UNSELECT_TICKETS, CHANGE_TICKETS_PAGE, SORT_TICKETS,

  LOAD_TICKET, UNLOAD_TICKET,
  LOAD_ACTIVITIES, UNLOAD_ACTIVITIES,

  CHANGE_CATEGORY, CHANGE_STATUS, CHANGE_DATE,
} from './actionTypes';

export default {
  remove(context) {
    const {Meteor, Store} = context;
    let tickets = Store.getState().tickets.list.selectedTickets;

    confirm.displayConfirmation(context, {        // <-- It can't seem to recognize this
      title: 'Removing Tickets',
      message: "<p>Are you sure you want to delete below tickets?<ul>{tickets.map((ticket, i) => <li key={'msg-' + i}>{ticket.ticketNo}</li>)}</ul></p>",
      callback: () => {
        Meteor.call('tickets.delete', tickets.map(ticket => ticket._id), (err) => {
          if (err) {
            return;
          }

          notify.sendNotify(context, `${tickets.map(ticket => ticket.ticketNo).join(', ')} ${tickets.length > 1 ? 'have' : 'has'} been deleted.`);
          unselect(context);
        });

      }
    });
  },
};
```

**../../core/actions/index.js**

```
import notify from './notify';
import confirm from './confirm';

export default {
  notify,
  confirm
};
```

**../../core/actions/confirm.js**

```
let dismissConfirmation = ({Store}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISMISS_CONFIRMATION
  });
};

export default {
  displayConfirmation({Store}, {title, message, callback}) {
    Store.dispatch({
      type: DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION,
      title,
      message,
      callback
    });
  },

  dismissConfirmation,

  confirm(context) {
    let {Store} = context;

    Store.getState().confirm.callback();
    dismissConfirmation(context);
  }
};
```

Any help mostly appreciated!

**-- EDIT --**

Have tried to change **confirm.js** to:

**../../core/actions/confirm.js**

```
export const dismissConfirmation = ({Store}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISMISS_CONFIRMATION
  });
};

export const displayConfirmation = ({Store}, {title, message, callback}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION,
    title,
    message,
    callback
  });
};

export const confirm = (context) => {
  let {Store} = context;

  Store.getState().confirm.callback();
  dismissConfirmation(context);
};
```

But still getting the same undefined error.

If I tried to change `confirm.displayConfirmation` to `displayConfirmation` at **actions/ticket.js**, will then get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: displayConfirmation is not a function
```

Comment: What is exported from `../../core/actions`?

Comment: Sorry typo, inside core/actions, there are one index file to import actions/confirm.js that's all.

Comment: Can you post the contents of that index file?

Comment: Posed index.js as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you confirm.js to this.

```
export const dismissConfirmation = ({Store}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISMISS_CONFIRMATION
  });
};


export const displayConfirmation({Store}, {title, message, callback}) {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION,
    title,
    message,
    callback
  });
},



export const confirm(context) {
  let {Store} = context;

  Store.getState().confirm.callback();
  dismissConfirmation(context);
}
```

Now you can import these functions in other files like this

```
import { 
  displayConfirmation, 
  confirm, 
  dismissConfirmation 
} from '../../core/actions';
```

You are mixing the concept of named exports with default export please read this article [Named exports vs default exports](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  I've tried as advised, but seems having same error.  See above.  Any clue?

Comment: I think you fixed it. If yes can you please masrk it as solved

Comment: Please check the updated answer it will help and I shared a link please follow that It will help you to understand the concept

Comment: Not solved yet.  As described above, will get the error instead:

'Uncaught TypeError: displayConfirmation is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mzparacha, below are the final changes.

**../../core/actions/confirm.js**

```
export const dismissConfirmation = ({Store}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISMISS_CONFIRMATION
  });
};

export const displayConfirmation = ({Store}, {title, message, callback}) => {
  Store.dispatch({
    type: DISPLAY_CONFIRMATION,
    title,
    message,
    callback
  });
};

export const confirm = (context) => {
  let {Store} = context;

  Store.getState().confirm.callback();
  dismissConfirmation(context);
};
```

However on the import part, did it as below instead:

**actions/ticket.js**

```
import * as confirm from '../../core/actions/confirm';
...
```

And the rest remains.  Works like charm.  Thank you @mzparacha

Comment: Thanks @leslie Leng